# Unable to resolve module './app/img/bg.png'

Tags: image, react-native

When I tried to set image source with below code then it's working fine

```
<Image source={require('/home/xbyte/Ravi/React Native/projects/saloonApp/app/img/bg.jpg')} style={styles.image} />
```

But then I tried to set image source like other users using below code at that time it's not working properly

```
<Image source={require('./app/img/bg.jpg')} style={styles.image} />
```

kindly please help me to get out of this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: First one is working proper coz first one has a full image path and the second one has a short path with ./ which means prefix will take automatically by the system while running but it's not working properly

Comment: "/home/xbyte/Ravi/React Native/projects/saloonApp/app/img/bg.jpg" this is path of image file and this file in my local storage

Comment: in this file "/home/xbyte/Ravi/React Native/projects/saloonApp/app/components/SplashScreen/index.js"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact problem is

Option 1

Move your images to drawable folder which is available at my-app-mobile\android\app\src\main\res\drawable

But for setting up images source use could uri as below

```
<Image source={{ uri: "bg.jpg" }} style={styles.deviceIcon} />
```

Option 2
Use a different command line as it seems your images are not bundled

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```